# Nginx serves php files as 'not found'

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to configure my nginx server to serve php files.

I have installed php 7.1 (with fpm) using brew. `php -v` and `phpfpm -v` gives me the good version.

My nginx config looks as follows:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  access_log  /Library/Logs/nginx/access.log  main;

  location / {
      root   /Users/tomek/Sites;
      index  index.html index.htm index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  #error_page  404              /404.html;

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  #
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably because of:

`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;`

Here is a sample nginx configuration file I use on my server and it should work fine for you too:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  _ default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    # Main Settings
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/YOUR_PHP_FOLDER;
        index  index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
        }

        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
            gzip_vary on; 
        }
    }

    # Handle Not Found Page
    error_page  404              /404.html;

    # Handle Server Errors
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # Disable Apache .htaccess
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```